# Indy Dynamic Create Server Client connecting error 10061

Tags: delphi, sockets, indy

I am having trouble dynamically creating some INDY communication.  I have not used Indy before and I can't get the server set up right.  I get the error 10061.  I have added a rule to the fire wall to allow this application and the port.  It works if I use TServerSocket and TClientSocket but I need to use Indy.

This code does not work

```
procedure TForm3.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  temp          : TIdSocketHandles;

begin
  fIdTCPServer1 := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
  fIdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  temp := TIdSocketHandles.Create(fIdTCPServer1);
  temp.Add.IP := 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';//'localhost'; //gave error when tryingn to use local host
  temp.Add.Port := 20200;

  fIdTCPServer1.Bindings := temp;
  fIdTCPServer1.OnExecute := IdTCPServer1Execute;
  fIdTCPServer1.StartListening();


  fIdTCPClient1.Port := 20200;
  fIdTCPClient1.Host := 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';//'localhost';
  fIdTCPClient1.Connect;  //error 10061 here

  fIdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('Some message');
end;
procedure TForm3.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  inStr : String;

begin
  inStr := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  ShowMessage('Server received : ' + inStr);
end;
```

This code works

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  serverSocket1 := TServerSocket.Create(nil);
  clientSocket1 := TClientSocket.Create(nil);

  serverSocket1.Port := 20200;
  serverSocket1.OnClientRead := ServerSocket1ClientRead;
  serverSocket1.Active := True;


  clientSocket1.Port := 20200;
  clientSocket1.Host := 'localhost';
  clientSocket1.Active := True;
  clientSocket1.Socket.SendText('Some message');
end;

procedure TForm3.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  inStr  : String;
begin
  inStr := Socket.ReceiveText();
  ShowMessage('Server received : ' + inStr);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both `IP` address and `port` on each binding.

```
// Here you're adding a binding and setting only the IP address
temp.Add.IP := 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';
// Here you're adding another binding and setting only the port
temp.Add.Port := 20200;
```

Here's an easy way to do it properly:

```
with fIdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add do
begin 
  IP := '127.0.0.1'; // Use IP address, not host name. Localhost = 127.0.0.1
  Port := 20200;
end;
```

Here's another, more verbose, way to do it (add `IdSocketHandle` to your uses clause):

```
var
  socketHandle: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  socketHandle := fIdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  socketHandle.IP := '127.0.0.1';
  socketHandle.Port := 20200;
end;
```

Also, to start it up, you just need to set Active to true like this:

```
fIdTCPServer1.Active := True;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. you are misusing the `TIdTCPServer.Bindings`, and you are not activating the server correctly.
2. you are calling `ShowMessage()` in the `OnExecute` event, but `TIdTCPServer` is multithreaded component (each connected client runs in its own thread) and `ShowMessage()` is not thread-safe.
3. you have some potential memory leaks in your code.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm3.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  temp : TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  if fIdTCPServer1 = nil then
  begin
    fIdTCPServer1 := TIdTCPServer.Create(Self);
    temp := fIdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
    temp.IP := 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';//'localhost'; //gave error when tryingn to use local host
    temp.Port := 20200;
    fIdTCPServer1.OnExecute := IdTCPServer1Execute;
    fIdTCPServer1.Active := True;
  end;

  if fIdTCPClient1 = nil then
  begin
    fIdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(Self);
    fIdTCPClient1.Port := 20200;
    fIdTCPClient1.Host := 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';//'localhost';
  end;

  fIdTCPClient1.Connect;
  fIdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('Some message');
end;

procedure TForm3.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  inStr : String;
begin
  inStr := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  Windows.MessageBox(0, PChar(inStr), PChar('Server received'), MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized it was not thread save, and could have memory leaks, but I was just trying to create a quick and short example.  It is good to note that though so no one tries to just copy what I did.